# Uppercase in name of a function in Julia

Tags: function, julia, uppercase

I am fairly new to Julia and got confused with the following code. After a function LucasTree is defined, it is used again as lt. Does Julia have some kind of role where I can recall a function using the uppercase abbreviation? If so, where can I find a nice reference for this feature?

```
function LucasTree(;γ = 2.0,
                   β = 0.95,
                   α = 0.9,
                   σ = 0.1,
                   grid_size = 100)

   ϕ = LogNormal(0.0, σ)
   shocks = rand(ϕ, 500)

   # build a grid with mass around stationary distribution
   ssd = σ / sqrt(1 - α^2)
   grid_min, grid_max = exp(-4ssd), exp(4ssd)
   grid = range(grid_min, grid_max, length = grid_size)

   # set h(y) = β * int u'(G(y,z)) G(y,z) ϕ(dz)
   h = similar(grid)
   for (i, y) in enumerate(grid)
       h[i] = β * mean((y^α .* shocks).^(1 - γ))
   end

   return (γ = γ, β = β, α = α, σ = σ, ϕ = ϕ, grid = grid, shocks = shocks, h = h)
end
```

```
function lucas_operator(lt, f)

    # unpack input
    @unpack grid, α, β, h = lt
    z = lt.shocks

    Af = LinearInterpolation(grid, f, extrapolation_bc=Line())

    Tf = [ h[i] + β * mean(Af.(grid[i]^α .* z)) for i in 1:length(grid) ]
    return Tf
end
```

Comment: Uppercase in a function name is usually reserved for [Constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/), although this is in no way enforced. However, the `LucasTree` function in the code you posted appears to return a `NamedTuple` to me, which is odd. I would have expected it to return an instance of the type `LucasTree` (where the type definition would be somewhere else in the package). The `lt` in the second function is an instance of some type (maybe `LucasTree`) that has a field `shocks` in it. Can you indicate where this code is from?

Comment: BTW, regarding: "Does Julia have some kind of role where I can recall a function using the uppercase abbreviation?", the answer is no, at least not for Base julia. This behaviour could possibly be implemented in a package by an appropriate macro but I haven't seen it before.

Comment: As far as I know, upper-case names like `LucasTree` are typically methods associated with a `struct` named `LucasTree`.

Comment: I think `lt` in this code is just the output of a call to `LucasTree`, as in `lt = LucasTree()` or `lt = LucasTree(α = 1.5)` for examples.

Comment: Sometimes named tuples are used as a sort of "lightweight" structs, instead of defining an actual struct type (I mean lightweight as in easy to define and modify, the performance is the same). I guess this is what `LucasTree` is doing. At a later step in the development, a full type would probably be defined.

Comment: Julia certainly has no functionality for referring to a function by an abbreviation. That would be a *terrible* feature. And I cannot see anything like that in the code. The identifier `lt` is just an ordinary variable name, used just like all variables are. The code would work exactly the same if the variable was called `x`, it's just called `lt` to show that it normally contains a `LucasTree` object (I presume), and then `lt` is more 'mnemonic' than `x`.

Comment: @ColinTBowers This code is from Quantecon and you can see the rest of the code https://julia.quantecon.org/multi_agent_models/lucas_model.html

Comment: Thanks folks for the comment, okay there is no abbreviation feature in Julia and this code (not my code) still works with different naming for the lt argument. Presumably, the naming is intentional to indicate it is associated with LucasTree struct. Many thanks to everyone!

Comment: @Judy Ah, I see. It appears DNF is correct, and they are using `LucasTree` as a sort of "lightweight" constructor. Personally, I think it is only a tiny additional effort to formally define the `LucasTree` struct and then use it explicitly, but I'm sure they had their reasons...

Comment: @ColinTBowers Agreed, seems like LucasTree is intended to be a struct in this setting. Maybe it is a personal writing style of the code writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this does not exist. It would be too nonunique to be practical, and moreover function names in Julia by convention *should* be entirely lowercase (structs/types can be CamelCase, but not functions, with the possible exception of constructors*).

In any case, all that is happening here in the code you have posted is that the function `lucas_operator` takes two arguments, `lt` and `f`, which can then be used within that `lucas_operator` function. These could in principle be anything, and regardless of what they are named outside the scope of the function, they will be named `lt` and `f` within the scope of the function. So for example:

```
function example(foo, bar)
    return foo(2*bar)
end
```

if you then call

```
example(somereallylongfunctionname, somevariable)
```

then that will return the equivalent of

```
somereallylongfunctionname(2*somevariable)
```

or similarly

```
example(SomeImproperlyCapitalizedFunction, somevariable)
# equivalent to SomeImproperlyCapitalizedFunction(2*somevariable)
```

in either case, regardless of its name outside the scope of the `example`  function, the first argument passed to the function will be known as `foo` within the function.

`*` Aside about constructors: that would be a function that is used to construct a custom type. This doesn't *quite* do that, but it does return an instance of a `NamedTuple` which then seems to be treated somewhat like a type/struct in the subsequent code, so perhaps it could be counted as a constructor.